# Firefox overlaps tables in a form

Tags: css, firefox

I have two tables in a form. The first has float:right, the second has no float.
When the width of the window becomes smaller by resizing or by zooming in, the tables become too wide to display them side by side. They should be displayed one after the other. The first one right aligned, the second one left aligned in the page.
IE, Chrome and Safari display this correctly. But Firefox 30.0 shifts the tables into overlap position.
Is this a Firefox bug or do I need to use something special here?

Comment: If you expect an answer you should post some actual markup and styles that demonstrate the issue. Use http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: When you say they "overlap", are you already controlling the "overflow" CSS setting? The tables themselves are on top of each other? I think you need to do some research into _responsive design_ (layout) to dynamically move block element positioning in response to display width.